# Why is this div so big?

Tags: html, css, dom

I'm doing site which will contain chat. I have a problem, why are these messages so high (`.chat_msg`)?

```
.chat_msg{
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 5px;
    width: 300px;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d2swdxgy/

Comment: Yeah, that seems crazy... May be because of the positioning?

Comment: Yeah, i also think that's the answer, but I don't know how to fix it :(

Comment: @irqize - It is because img, div are block level elements. Even though you have re-positioned the divs, they still hold the place below images. Just add display:inline to all these and see the change.

Comment: @irqize I have solved the issue. Have a look at it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it using this:

```
.chat_msg {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 50px;
}

.chat_msg img {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
}
```

You are supposed to give the `<img />` a `position: absolute` and not `relative` and give the parent a `min-height`, so that the `<img />` doesn't get overlapped. This is how I have been doing.

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/d2swdxgy/3/**

Comment: Now its height is good, but it's not still ok. Last elemnt doesn't show login and message, why?

Comment: @irqize It is not the last box, it is the first box. Correcting it. Please wait.

Comment: Yeah, couldn't be better. Thank you a lot for help.

Comment: @irqize Example with more content, working perfectly fine: https://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/d2swdxgy/6/

Comment: @PraveenKumar Nice job, clear and well explained. I was trying to solve the problem but I up vote this :)

Comment: @Franco Sure buddy... Thanks for your support. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this :)

https://jsfiddle.net/d2swdxgy/5/

Just fixed the CSS

```
.chat_msg{
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 5px;
    width: 300px;
    clear: both;
}
.chat_msg img{
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    margin: 5px;
    float: left;
}
.chat_msg_login{
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
.chat_msg_msg{
    text-align: justify;
}
#chat{
    height: 400px;
    width: 300px;
    border-width:5px;
    border-style:dashed;
}
#chat_msgs_box{
    height:400px;
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: When the chat message is too long, the message garbles. Check.

Comment: Still it has issues... :)

Answer (score 0):

```
.chat_msg {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  display:inline;
 }

 .chat_msg img {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
 }
```

just make it responsive.